# Internet Explorer compatibility mode

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a ASP.NET web application which is supposed to work on IE.
If I go to compatibility View Settings and uncheck Display intranet sites in Compatibility View and the domain is not added in the box Websites you've added in Compatibility View, the users sees the code not the forms of the page.
If I check the checkbox, he still sees the code, only after I add it in the box I can see the actual forms of the page.
I tried

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=IE5" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

but still the same problem.
Is there another way to force it from code? I understand in the future the checkbox will be disabled so I must find I way to force the compatibility mode.

Can I add it to the box for Compatiblity View from code?